# how to make a setInterval stop after some time

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a loading function that displays text with a delay of 6 seconds for 4 seconds, then it should stop and the function should be executed loadingStop function

```
function loading() {
  let abc = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
  let i = 0;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setInterval(() => {
        i = (i > 5) ? 0 : i;
        //console.clear();
        console.log(abc[i]);
        i++;
        const error = false;
        if (!error) {
          resolve();
        } else {
          reject('Error: smth went wrong')
        }
      }, 300);
    }, 6000)
  })
};

function loadingStop() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('some text');
  }, 4000);
}
loading().then(loadingStop);
```

but loadingStop function didn't stop loading

Comment: Can you add where you're calling the functions from?

Comment: Assign the result of `setInterval` to a variable, then call `clearInterval` when you want it to stop.

Comment: This whole notion of polling some variable value with `setInterval()` is a broken way of doing things.  There are better ways.  You'd have to show the larger problem for us to suggest how you simplify this.

Answer (score 2):

Can use `clearInterval(timerId)`, for given example.

```js
function loading() {
  let abc = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];
  let i = 0;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const timerId = setInterval(() => {
      i = i > 5 ? 0 : i;
      console.log(abc[i]);
      i++;
    }, 300);
    setTimeout(() => {
      clearInterval(timerId);
      reject("Error: smth went wrong");
    }, 6000);
  });
}

function loadingStop() {
  console.log("some text");
}
loading().then(loadingStop).catch(console.error);
```

Comment: @Roamer-1888. I gave him a sample he can solve the issue.

Comment: Yup, fair enough. You can see my own interpretation in my own answer. Stay safe, friend.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to save the interval to a variable first

```
const interval = setInterval(() => console.log('Hi'), 3000);
```

Then use **clearInterval** to clear/end it

```
clearInterval(interval);
```

Answer (score 0):

can you define setInterval in the variable, when you want stop the setInterval, you call function clearInterval(varname), clearInterval is a native function of js to stop the setInterval, I hope help you.

```
var intervalx = setInterval(function(
   console.log('hello')
}, 1000);

clearInterval(intervalx);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure I understand exactly what's required here but possibly ...

- start an animation which resolves/rejects a Promise on completion
- cause the animation to stop after a specified timeout period (to be reported as error).
- if some arbitrary event occurs before the timeout, then stop the animation (to be reported as normal completion).

If so, then much of the code in the question is fine. It just lacks a mechanism to force the animation to stop before the timeout occurs.

That can be achieved by passing a token (a JS plain object) to `loaing()`.

```
function loading(token) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Basic animation data
        let abc = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];
        let i = 0;

        // Establish a stoppable animation
        let timerId = setInterval(() => {
            if(token.stop) { // has stop command been issued?
                clearInterval(timerId); // kill the animation
                resolve('stopped');
            } else {
                console.log(abc[i]); // the "animation"
                i = (i+1) % 5;
            }
        }, 300);

        // Stop the animation after a certain timeout period
        setTimeout(() => {
            clearInterval(timerId); // kill the animation
            reject(new Error("time out")); // always reject with an Error
        }, 6000);
    });
}

// Token (allows a "stop" command to be issued)
let token = {};

// Simulated "stop" event
setTimeout(() => {
    token.stop = true;
}, 4000);

// Call loading() and log normal/error completion.
loading(token).then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

As written, with the stop command issued after 4 seconds, "stopped" will be logged.

By changing `4000` to say `8000`, the timeout will occur before the stop command and "Error: 'time out'" will be logged.

In practice, you would probably want to give yourself a measure of flexibility by passing `6000` and maybe `300` to `loading()` as parameters.